# How to prevent page navigation when pressing Backspace key in the iframe area without allow-scripts

Tags: javascript, iframe, dom-events, sandbox, preventdefault

The default page navigation behavior of the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key has been prevented for the whole document. However, when the focus is in the iframe area, pressing the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key still causes page navigation to the previous web page.

Here is a simple example. The first web page page1.html contains a link to the second web page page2.html which has an iframe. To reproduce the problem, open page1.html in a web browser and then click the link in page1 to navigate to page2.html. If the mouse is focused at any place except the iframe area in page2, it will stay at the same page (page2.html) after pressing the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key; if the mouse is focused at the iframe area, it will navigate to the previous page (page1.html).

**page1.html**

```
<html>
<body>
This is page 1. <br/>
<a href="page2.html"> Click to page 2 with iframe. </a><br/>
</body>
</html>
```

**page2.html**

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.onkeydown = function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 8) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    };
</script>
<body>
This is page 2 with iframe.<br/>
<iframe width="200" height="50" name="box" id="box" sandbox="allow-same-origin"></iframe><br/>
</body>
</html>
```

The code in `document.onkeydown` is not fired when the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key is pressed in the iframe area. It works fine when the focus is at anywhere else.

I found if scripts is allowed in the sandbox of iframe, changing **page2.html** to the following will prevent the page navigation when the focus is in the iframe area. But due to the security issues, our project could NOT allow scripts for this iframe.

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.onkeydown = function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 8) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    };
</script>
<body>
This is page 2 with iframe.<br/>
<iframe width="200" height="50" name="box" id="box" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts"></iframe><br/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.frames[0].onkeydown = function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 8) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any solution for this problem without allow scripts for the iframe?